# ConnectionTimeoutError AWS elasticsearch using Django elasticsearch-dsl

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Not sure what's going on: I am trying to deploy and create the ES index `python manage.py search_index --rebuild -f`  however I am getting this error:

```
ConnectTimeoutError((<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10e8790a0>, 'Connection to vpc-xxxxx.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com timed out
```

I have custom TCP listening to port 9200 in my security group.

Also in my settings file:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': https://vpc-xxxxx.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com,
    },
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find out why this happens? of find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect to AWS Elasticsearch on port 9200?
If yes, please note that AWS Elasticsearch works over port 80 and 443 and **does not** use the default port 9200.